# How to Autocomplete Dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

**I need to get the list of employee in autocomplete.**

**I am new to asp.net, I am using the same way as we used to show the details of any employee etc, Included all the necessary files.**

```
<body>
@*@foreach(var temp in Model){
       var temporary = @temp.name;
}*@
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

```
<script>
debugger
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temporary=[@foreach(var temp in Model){@temp.name}];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: temporary
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult autocomplete() {
        var temp = db.employees.ToList();
        //ViewBag.menus = temp;
        //return View(temp);
        return View(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what is returned by your controller? Any errors in your console? What versions of jQuery and UI are you using?

Comment: No error
my list of employees name is not visible as a intelligence in the.
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Does `var temporary=[@foreach(var temp in Model){@temp.name}];` result in the proper syntax for an Array?

Comment: I am getting the values from this coding. Though Idk the approach is good or bad

Comment: I would advise you use View Source on your resulting page and look in the script section, it must contain the proper details or it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the several changes and follow a tutorial
**Mycontroller:-**

```
 public ActionResult autocomplete()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult getautomate(string term)
    {
        var temp = db.employees.Where(x => x.name.StartsWith(term)).Select(y=>y.name).ToList();
        return Json(temp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**My View:-**

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm()) {
   <b>name:</b>
    @Html.TextBox("searchterm", null, new {id="textsearch" })

    @*<input type="submit" value="search"/>*@
    }

 $(function () {
    $("#textsearch").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("getautomate")',
        minLength:2,
    });
});
```